# Conditional formatting skipping zeros and alternate columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet where in alternating columns I list Supplier pack size and price per unit.  I want to highlight the cell(s) in this range with the lowest price per unit, ignoring zeros.  How can I do this?

Currently, I have 3 formatting rules:

```
=MOD(COLUMN(A2), 2) = 1 (No format, stop when true)
=A2 = 0 (No format, stop when true)
=A2=SMALL(A2:F2,COUNTIF(A2:F2,0)+1) (Green background)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work if the smallest value above zero happens to be eliminated by the first rule.

How can I modify the formula so that it effectively ignores the values in the Pack Size columns?  Alternatively, is there another way of doing this?

This is what I currently have:

[image: What I have]

After applying the conditional formatting this is what it should look like:

[image: Lowest PPU highlighted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate the smallest price without 0 like the following in I1 for example

`=SMALL(IF((--MOD(COLUMN(A2:H2),2)=0)*(A2:H2)>0,(--MOD(COLUMN(A2:H2),2)=0)*(A2:H2),""),1)`
and press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` at the same time
It is an array formula
After having the smallest price select the Data where you want to apply conditional formatting and choose the rule :
`=A2=$I$1*(--(MOD(COLUMN(),2)=0))`
Choose the format you want (you can just write `=A2=$I$1` to A2 in conditional formatting rule and choose the format, later use `Format Painter` to copy the conditional formatting to other prices)